# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): param.map is not a function

Tags: web3js, javascript, ethereumjs, react, ethers.js

Using `Web3`to execute transactions, and getting the following error:

> Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): param.map is not a function
> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: param.map is not a function
> at ABICoder.push../node_modules/web3-eth/node_modules/web3-eth-abi/lib/index.js.ABICoder.formatParam

Here is the snippet of code:

```js
const detectEth = async () => {
    if (window.ethereum) {
      window.web3 = new web3(window.ethereum);
      await window.ethereum.enable()
    }
    else if (window.web3) {
      window.web3 = new web3(window.web3.currentProvider);
    }
    else {
      window.alert('Non-Ethereum browser detected. You should consider trying MetaMask!')
    }
  };

const mint = async () => {
    detectEth();

    const web3 = window.web3;

    const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(NFT_ABI, NFT_CONTRACT_ADDRESS, { gasLimit: "1000000" });

// This function works well
    const mintFees = await nftContract.methods.mintFees().call({
      from: accountAddress,
      to: NFT_CONTRACT_ADDRESS
    });

// ERROR coming from this line
    contract.methods.claim(index, hash, proof, id).send({
      from: accountAddress,
      value: mintFees
    }, (error, transactionHash) => {
        if (error) {
          console.log('In Error');
          console.log(error);
          hideSpinner();
        }
      });
}
```

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was having undefined params.

Comment: Do you mean that some of the call parameters `contract.methods.claim(index, hash, proof, id)` were undefined?

Comment: Which of the params was undefined?

Answer (score 0):

Faced this same error myself.

Basically, one of the parameters here - index, hash, proof, id - should be passed in as an array. Check the type of input in the ABI or the block explorer and it'll show accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The claim function was expecting an array in one of it's arguments, check the contract which one was requesting array, if its the id as example change  `contract.methods.claim(index, hash, proof, id)` to  `contract.methods.claim(index, hash, proof, [id])`